# Matrix similar if $M^{k}=I_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let M be some $n \times n$-Matrix.

If we have $M^{k}=I_n$ for some positiv k, is $M$ then similar to $I_n$?

Comment: A matrix $M$ similar to $I$ must be $I$, see the duplicate. So take any other $M$ with $M^k=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $M=PI_nP^{-1}$ then 
$$M=PP^{-1}=I_n$$

**Hint 2:** The matrix 
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
0& 1 \\
-1 &0
\end{bmatrix}$$
satisfies $A^4=I_2$.